# How are the divisor of SP500 determined?

Tags: sp500

I read through the definition of S&P 500, there is no clear explanation of the Divisor.

I wonder what is it and where can I read more about it?

Comment: S&P500 is a market cap weighted index

Comment: @noob2 That is true, so?

Comment: This link might help: https://finance.zacks.com/index-divisor-2407.html

Answer (score 5):

The divisor is just a random fixed number. The current market cap of the SPX is around 25.64 trillions. The value of the SPX at the moment is 3,185.04 .

This means that the divisor is around 25,640,000,000,000/3,185. But that number is completely irrelevant and has no economic meaning.

Comment: Yes, if you want more details: The S&P company designed the current index in 1957. They scaled it so it would have the average value 10 over the period 1941-1943. An arbitrary decision, but they have kept consistency since then (as they must). Once an initial value is chosen it determines the scaling factor.

Comment: S&P 500 divisor is neither devoid of any economic meaning nor a fixed number. While it is not very useful standalone, it represents one-tenth of average extrapolated total free-float market cap of stocks in S&P 500 from 1941 through 1943 in million \$, adjusted for certain types of corporate actions of stocks that have been in S&P 500 since then. As of end-June 2020, S&P 500 price index's divisor was 8,269.11 million \$ (or approx. 8.3 billion \$). Divisor changes frequently on new corporate actions (possibly more than once a week) and has risen significantly since S&P 500's launch in 1957.

Comment: @Alper Thanks for your input. I am actually mildly interested in what you said, are there some reading related to this for more detail?

Comment: @PrestonLui Check out [Standard & Poor's 500 Index Calculation](https://www.cftech.com/the-brainbank-archive/finance/138-standard-poor-s-500-index-calculation) article, [S&P 500 webpage](https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/equity/sp-500) for info including past divisor values in “Index Earnings” Excel file, the [Index Calculation Primer](https://www.crainsdetroit.com/assets/PDF/CD1084251221.PDF) presentation, [article by NYT](https://timesmachine.nytimes.com/timesmachine/1957/03/05/85000360.html?pageNumber=41) when S&P 500 was launched. Note same divisor is used in S&P 500 index and EPS.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P_500#Index_value_calculation) actually has a decent explanation of the divisor:

> The *Divisor*, currently below 8.3 billion, is a number that is adjusted to keep the value of the index consistent despite corporate actions that affect market capitalization and would otherwise affect the calculation formula, such as additional share issuance, share buybacks, special dividends, constituent changes, rights offerings, and corporate spin-offs. Stock splits do not affect the divisor since they do not affect market capitalization. When a company is dropped and replaced by another with a different market capitalization, the divisor needs to be adjusted in such a way that the value of the S&P 500 index remains constant. All divisor adjustments are made after the close of trading and after the calculation of the closing value of the S&P 500 index.

There's not a "formula" per se for the divisor. It's adjusted to keep the index consistent when there's a corporate action (share buyback, spin-off, etc.) that would affect the market cap of the company, or when the index constituents change. So the divisor is the accumulation of years' worth of individual adjustments.

Say, for example, that the index value is 100 and a company that makes up 10% of the index pays a special 5% dividend. The value of the stock would drop by 5% as well (because the value of the company is reduced accordingly), but it does not reflect a 5% drop in the *wealth* of an investor. If the divisor were not adjusted, the index would drop by (100 * 10% * 5%). So the divisor would be adjusted so that the index value would be adjusted back up to it's pre-dividend amount.

Or, suppose a company that has a market cap of \$10 Billion is dropped and replaced by a company with a market cap of \$20 Billion. That change would change the index value since the new company would have more weight in the new index, so the divisor is adjusted to keep the index value consistent after the replacement.

Comment: Could someone please explain, what does it mean 'to keep the index consistent', specifically in this example: *suppose a company that has a market cap of \$10 Billion is dropped and replaced by a company with a market cap of \$20 Billion. That change would change the index value*? Isn't this a case where it should be said that the index 'grew N points'? I really can't grasp the notion of the consistent index value, when I'm trying to understand what does it mean 'the index is up/down'. **It looks like the whole idea of the index is to be not consistent**

Comment: It looks like I got the idea. The purpose of the divisor is to prevent the index changed, when no changes in shares prices have occurred. In that example *a company that has a market cap of \$10 Billion is dropped and replaced* since the shares didn't change their price (precisely at the moment of the replacement), the index should not change, since the market hasn't changed. **Otherwise, if the divisor wasn't present, it would look like the market went up N points.**